# Arch Linux - make: error while loading shared libraries: libunistring

Tags: arch-linux, make, libraries, pacman, yaourt

I keep getting this same error when trying to install various packages:

```
make: error while loading shared libraries: libunistring.so.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It's occurred while trying to install the Ruby gem Gosu as well as some free Linux games like Alien Arena. I even tried re-installing libunistring with pacman to no avail.

Comment: Please post the output of `pacman -Q libunistring`

Comment: Output for pacman -Q libunistring: libunistring 0.9.4-1

Comment: That PKGBUILD (ruby-gosu) is out of date, but with a small modification it builds fine. Is your glibc up-to-date? Are you using yaourt (because you should build manually if it fails)? Also, please don't paste truncated error output: it makes it too hard to guess what is going on, paste the whole thing.

Comment: I think the issue is with make itself. For example, if I just type `make` or `make -v`, I get the following output (non-truncated): `make: error while loading shared libraries: libunistring.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Then your system is likely out-of-date, or you have borked it somehow. Run `pacman -Syyu`.

Comment: What was this supposed to do? I can't even connect to WiFi now

Comment: It force syncs your mirror and updates your system: it is how Arch works... As for your wifi issue, that is a separate question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help! Everything is working fine now.

Comment: It's ridiculous: I install a fresh `base/arch` image, I run `pacman -S make`, it succeeds, I run `make` and it says `make: error while loading shared libraries: libunistring.so.2`. Arch Linux sux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pacman -Syyu
```

Fixed the issue as provided by [jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6761/jasonwryan).